# Spring Boot and how to configure connection details to MongoDB on cloud foundry?

Tags: spring, mongodb, cloud, cloud-foundry

I am currently creating a spring boot web application using mongodb. Locally I am able to run my application and data are being retrieved and stored.
but not on cloud foundry. Any tips, links or anything to help me will be greatly appreciated!

**Problem**

When I pushed it into cloud foundry, I am unable to connect to my mongodb. I know that we have to configure something on cloud foundry to make it work. I tried using the mongodb PCF, even when I bind it to my application it is still not running my application. I have been scouring through the internet trying to find the correct configurations to do so.

**Other thoughts**

I never set up an username and password when I was using MongoDb. I am currently just using localhost with port27017. Maybe I need to configure the credentials on my V_CAP or env varibles, But I cannot edit those on the UI of cloudfoundry.com. Would there be a command line prompt to configure those varibles into cf? I check out several documents but I am unclear where to add these beans into which configuration file or would it help get mongodb running on the cloud foundry [Doc1](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_mongodb)

**Error of connection on cloud foundry**

> OUT
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'apL'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'appPortList': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out
>   after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
>   ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of
>   cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017,
>   type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
>   socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}];
>   nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after
>   30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
>   ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of
>   cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017,
>   type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING,
>   exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening
>   socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]

Comment: Are you on PWS (Pivotal Web Services) or on Bluemix, or on Swisscom? Using mongodb might be slightly different on these PaaSes.

Comment: PWS, How can I create mongodb user name and password so that I can pass it into these varibles.

Comment: Username and password should be created by PWS for you. You can see them by inspecting the environment of your application -- e.g. by running `cf env <your_app_name>`

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, Spring boot cloud connectors should do this for you, but I have had problems with it in the past.

Alternatively, you need to add a spring bean extending AbstractMongoConfiguration. In this configuration you must insert the host, port, username, database name, and password you find in the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable.

You could automatically insert this by getting the value of the VCAP_SERVICES variable using System.getEnv("VCAP_SERVICES"), and parse it with JACKSON, or some other JSON library.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return this.databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        List<ServerAddress> serverAddresses = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress("my_host", 7777);
        serverAddresses.add(address);
        return new MongoClient(serverAdresses,
                singletonList(
                        MongoCredential.createCredential(
                                "my_user_name",
                                "my_database_name",
                                "my_password".toCharArray()
                        )
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Regarding your "other thoughts". There is no way of editing the VCAP_SERVICES variable provided by CloudFoundry. Instead it should be read by your application, such that your application knows where to find the mongodb instance that CF has provided for it.

You can, however, add more environment variables to your application using 'cf set-env'. Yet this will not help to solve your problem as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I read up more about this configuration? I implemented your script above, I have error on returning this.databasename and singletonList.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good blog post about binding to data services on CF on the Spring Framework blog: https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry.

This post uses relational with JPA in its examples, but everything shown works for MongoDB also.

Comment: I stumbled upon your github example, You binded mongodb with your application using cloud profile. Where does the data go once you have binded mongodb with your app? I am trying to find all my stored data.

Comment: You likely want to get a MongoDbFactory bean into the app context, as in this example: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/config/data/MongoCloudConfig.java. Then create a Spring Data MongoDB Repository bean as in this example: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/samples/music/repositories/mongodb/MongoAlbumRepository.java. The Repository bean will use the MongoDbFactory bean.

Comment: Yes, that the examples I have seen, Where can I access the stored data? Such as a on local machine I can use command line db.collection.find() and it queries all my values. How can I do the same for the mongo-cloud?\

Comment: Accessing the data in MongoDB depends entirely on the MongoDB implementation. If you are using PWS as stated above then mLab is hosting your MongoDB. See the docs at http://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/mlab.html and http://docs.mlab.com/.